# Create a single aspx page to send email

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have a html form on DNN website. This form will submit data to an aspx file which on the same host with DNN website. This aspx file will process the data and sending an email. Is this possible? I don't want to write a DNN plugin for this simple job.

Comment: I have only notepad++ and ftp client? Does aspx page need compile or just upload it on server and browse to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just put your ASPX Email Sender (and, potentially, its code-behind fild) in the same folder sub-tree that your DNN site is located.
2. Make sure that your ASPX file is not named the same as a DotNetNuke page
3. You will not need to compile this page; it will be compiled dynamically, as are several ASPX files built into DNN.